How to move a specific number of files into a newly created incremental folder
I am trying to create a script that will create a folder let's say folder1, folder2, folder3, etc. And will then move the first 5 files into folder1 and then the next 5 into folder2 so on and so forth. I can get the script to create the folders but then not move the files into the folders. My script is as below. I think it is struggling to understand the variables but it also isn't throwing any errors. Any help would be much appreciated.
cd c:\temp\
1..5 | ForEach-Object { 
    md "Folder $_"
}

$Folders = "C:\temp\Folder*"

foreach ($Folders in "C:\temp") {
    $filesPerFolder = 5
    $sourcePath = 'C:\temp'
    $destPath = 'C:\temp\$Folders'

    $sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -File
    if (!(Get-ChildItem -Path $destPath)) {
        $sourceFiles | Select-Object -First $filesPerFolder | Move-Item -Destination $destPath
    }
}


What if the directory has more than 25 files? Do you want to keep creating Folder 6 through Folder N?

The request was a set number of folders but I think it being incremental until all the files have been moved into the folders I think is more what we are looking for.


I think it being incremental until all the files have been moved into the folders I think is more what we are looking for

In that case I'd suggest creating the folders lazily, ie. not until you actually need one.
Use a while loop to continue until no files are left in the directory:
$rootFolder = "C:\temp"
$subFolderPrefix = "Folder"
$filesPerFolder = 5

$folderNum = 1

# keep fetching 1 file at a time until no files can be found
while ($nextFile = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $sourcePath -File |Select -First 1) {
    # calculate the next destination path, create folder if not already existing
    $destinationName = $subFolderPrefix,$folderNum -join ' '
    $destinationPath = Join-Path $sourcePath $destinationName
    if (-not(Test-Path -LiteralPath $destinationPath)) {
        Write-Host "Creating $destinationPath"
        $null = mkdir $destinationPath
    }

    # check if the next destination has room for more files
    if (@(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $destinationPath -File).Count -lt $filesPerFolder) {
        $nextFile |Move-Item -Destination $destinationPath -Force
    }
    else {
        # otherwise advance to the next destination folder
        $folderNum++
    }
}


Just create the new subdirectory, assign it to a variable, then get only the first 5 files in the base directory and move them in the newly made subdirectory
You might want to add Sort-Object before Select-Object if the order of the file you want is not the alphabetic one, though that might nullify Select-Object's ability to stop Get-ChildItem.
1..5 | ForEach-Object { 
    # make new directory and assign it to a variable.  
    $NewDest = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Path -Name "Folder $_" 

    # Get the files in the base directory.  
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File | 
        # Select-Object has the nice feature of STOPPING Get-ChildItem once it
        # receives the specified amount of files.   
        # Pretty nice when dealing with vast amount of files and\or asking for
        # files over a slow connection.   
        Select-Object -First 5 | 
        # Move the files to the new directory
        Move-Item -Destination $NewDest
}

